# How do I rename the .git directory?

Tags: git, rename

How do I rename the **.git directory**?

Say for instance I have a repo that I have been working with for some time but now I decide to rename the .git directory.  I tried the bash mv command but after I did that git status said the my working directory is not a git repository.

Comment: Why did you decide to do that?

Comment: whyever would you want to rename the **.git** directory? that's like wanting to rename the **git** command to something else. are you sure you don't just want to rename the `repo` directory?

Comment: @anirvan well, actually, should you rename the git command, it would still work ;)

Comment: @anirvan, I can't speak for OP, but the reason I want to rename the .git dir is to have a local git repo for a project that is also managed in TFS. TFS sees the .git folder and assumes that I'm just using git, such that I can't both connect to the TFS repo and have the solution open simultaneously.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No idea why you would ever want to rename that, but anyway...

Git expects :

- either a `.git` directory to exist under the current directory, or one of its parents,
- or the `GIT_DIR` environment variable to be set.

Generally, unless very special circumstances are in effect, you should never tread apart from `.git`. It is this directory which contains everything (the same way Subversion 1.7+ uses a `.svn` directory and CVS uses `CVS` directories -- only that git only uses one directory at the root)

The only exception to this are bare repositories, for which you need to be in the git directory itself -- but you normally *never* touch these directly unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: Subversion also only uses a single directory at the project root since v1.7

Comment: Maybe I am just not understanding something about the way Git works.  For instance, when I clone a remote repo like:

git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git

How is it that the Git directory is access via ../git.git ?

Answer (score 10):

You cannot and should not rename the `.git` directory itself, it is a fixed name (well, unless you pass `--git-dir=` to every git command or set the `GIT_DIR` environment variable). Git searches for this directory when it performs operations on the repository, such as `git status`.

Why do you decide you want to rename the `.git` directory? If you want to rename the repository, simply rename the parent directory of `.git`.

Comment: I found it useful to have a git repo rooted at my ~/ directory to track my dotfiles, and see what changes various apps made to the config files. However IDE such as eclipse, detect the ~/workspace (even ignored) and frequently can cause lengthy operations such as an un-cached "git status" on a big dir. There are ways to exclude the root repo from each tool using preferences, but it is simpler to rename the .git dir to .git_alt, and just pass in --git-dir=~/.git_alt when I want to track something related to my homedir git repo.

Comment: One reason to do this is because OneDrive (for Business) doesn't get along well with folders that change their contents a LOT (e.g. git).  I'm thinking of changing my active repositories hidden git folder name so that I can "make" OneDrive ignore it (by using invalid characters such as < or >).   According to Microsoft's response on Uservoice.com, they aren't planning on implementing a global ignore for these kinds of paths any time soon (so, adding invalid characters is a potential workaround).

Comment: It's impossible to get Visual Studio to ignore a .git folder and not-switch the source control plugin if it exists even though it should be using TFS for source control.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't.**

Git determines whether you're in a repository by looking for the `.git` directory in the current directory, then the parent directory, and so on up the tree.* If you rename it, Git has no idea where to look. Fix your repository by renaming it back to `.git`.

If you're actually trying to accomplish something here besides simply renaming directories for fun, edit your question or ask a new one about your real problem.

---

<sub>* In order to support bare repositories, which essentially just contain the contents of the .git directory at the top level, it also looks for certain files.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because of a bug in Visual Studio 2013 (VS 2013) in combination with the TFS tool. The TFS-project does not connect or start when it finds a local .git-Project which you added before.

First close VS 2013 and then rename the '.git' file to another postfix (e. g. "test.gitRENAMED"). This makes the connection to TFS-projects available again at the next start of VS 2013.

To avoid a broken local git-repository please name the '.git'-file back afterwards.

Unfortunately the windows-explorer does not allow you to name a directory back to '.git' because of their user-directory-policies.

**Just rename the folder on a Linux machine or via the Windows-Explorer-Tool "Total Commander" back.**

Answer (score -1):

You can't rename the .git directory. Git needs to be able to find it.